# Correlation between 2 stocks

Tags: returns, correlation

If Stock A returns 5% on average in year Y
And Stock B returns 2% on average in year Y

Does this mean that correlation is 40%?

Comment: Do you know what does correlation mean? I am voting to close this question as it lacks context.

Comment: Yes, I know the formula. But this was asked in an interview and the problem was I started thinking that within the data we have it can be concluded that when a stocks returns 5% the other returns 2% in a broader way. It's meaningless though. That's where I was confused.

Comment: You can add more background to your question to make it more meaningful.

Comment: There is no background. Except that price of stock A is 5 times price of stock B. But the thing I now realised is, what if stock A went up and down ( for simplicity ) and stock B went down and up in the same period, then correlation would look negative but how do I answer the question?

Answer (score 3):

*Does this mean that correlation is 40%?* No.

Very simple example (in R). Let A and B be stocks with returns `stockA` and `stockB`. Consider following example:

```
stockA = c(0.05, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06)
stockB = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.02)
mean(stockA)
mean(stockB)
cor(stockA, stockB)

stockA = c(0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.06)
stockB = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03)
mean(stockA)
mean(stockB)
cor(stockA, stockB)
```

giving

```
> mean(stockA)
[1] 0.05
> mean(stockB)
[1] 0.02
> cor(stockA, stockB)
[1] 0
> 
> stockA = c(0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.06)
> stockB = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03)
> mean(stockA)
[1] 0.05
> mean(stockB)
[1] 0.02
> cor(stockA, stockB)
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.  First, the question is ambiguous about what year Y is.  Is year Y actually 2015? Knowing those returns in one year says nothing about correlation.  Second, if it means that if Stock A goes up 5% then Stock B will go up by 2%, then that also says nothing.  What if Stock A goes down. Does stock B go up or down? Additionally, look at the averages.  Create a series of every year Stock A goes up by exactly 2%. Then one can create any correlation you want, positive or negative, by playing with the Stock B returns. For example lots of small negative returns, and one large positive gets a negative correlation at the same time as a 2% average.  [for example, in time series terms, A is up 2% exactly each time, but B goes from 1 to .9, .8, .7, .6, and then up to .95. The return is about 2% but the correlation would be negative 0.4 rather than positive 0.4]